# Pair bluetooth devices to a computer without verifying passkey

Tags: c#, android, windows, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an Android application to control the mouse on my Windows 7 notebook remotely via Bluetooth.

I have a C# WinForm that is a server and an Android tablet is the client. I am able to pair them together successfully by accepting the connections on both the server and client.

The problem is I want them to pair automatically, without the server manually accepting the pairing.

I have been stuck at this for the past 3 weeks and assignment deadline is this Friday.

Desperately pleading some experts on assistance :(

**Edited:**

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

        BluetoothClient clientBluetooth;
        BluetoothListener serverBluetooth;
        Guid mUUID = new Guid("{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}");

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            trayMenu = new ContextMenu();
            trayMenu.MenuItems.Add(0,
                new MenuItem("Quit", new System.EventHandler(quit_Click)));

            notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = trayMenu;
            notifyIcon1.MouseDoubleClick += notifyIcon1_MouseDoubleClick;

            clientBluetooth = new BluetoothClient();
            serverBluetooth = new BluetoothListener(mUUID);
            serverBluetooth.Start();
        }
    }
```

**Android:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the window
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}
```

.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        // Invoke when a Bluetooth device is found
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When a remote Bluetooth device is found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
                // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle("Select a device to connect");
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = "No device found".toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            } 
        }
    };
```

I also tried this:

```
private void clientConnect()
    {

        BluetoothDeviceInfo[] pairedDevicesList = clientBluetooth.DiscoverDevices();

        foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in pairedDevicesList)
        {
            if (!clientBluetooth.Connected)
            {
                BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(device.DeviceAddress, "123456");
            }

        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work too. The Bluetooth connection changes from "Listening..." to "Connecting..." and back to "Listening..."

Comment: [Ask] what have you tried so far? I don't know how to help with your question, but others will be more willing to if you show what you've tried already.

Comment: @john Thank you john for your prompt reply. Added the codes I've tried.